# Framework совместимость с Core

Tags: c#

Если `dll` написана на `.NET Framework 2.0`, будет ли она работать на `.NET Core 1.1` и выше ?

Comment: Думаю, что будет, но будут предупреждения о возможной несовместимости.

Comment: ага ;-) , особенно если она ссылается на компоненты, которые не мигрировали на core1.1